# Using the len() function with unicode values

Tags: python

Python newbie here.
I have an excel file with 5000 rows and 1 columns.
I'm importing them into Python and will then use if...else
statements to check for specific conditions.

So my data looks like: (in excel)

```
Kansas
Colorado
Missouri
Iowa
New York
New Mexico
mycar
car
thisisacar
...
```

There here is the code to import it into Python and the conditional 
statements.

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xls")

wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for item in sh.col(0):
    value = unicode(item.value)
    if value.startswith("car"):
        print value 
        if len(value) == 3:
            print value
```

The idea is to print everything with "car", and then print 
value when it only has a length of 3.

The `if len(value) == 3` doesn't seem to work. help!

Comment: And so what *does* it contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len(value)` should work fine -- I suggest there's probably some trailing whitespace or similar, so try using `len(value.strip())` and see if that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for `mycar` and `thisisacar`.

Maybe you should try something like:

```
x = (value.strip() for value in sh.col(0) if 'car' in value)
for i in x:
    print i
    if len(i) == 3:
        print i
```